# What event can I use to trigger a progress bar in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that opens in Microsoft Access.  The form is open from a menu.
This form has a tab control that always opens on one page, and on that page are four unbound object controls that display charts.  When the form opens, those charts are refreshed.

What event should I use to tell when this form first opens, and then when all the charts are refreshed?  I'm trying to put a progress bar there (I know how to do the progress bar itself, I just don't know what the proper event would be).

Comment: Try the form Load event.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  The progress bar appeared before the form came up, and there's no way to tell whether the unbound object controls are finished refreshing the charts.

Comment: There is no such event as refresh and load of controls happens in the background during loading of the form. The _OnCurrent_ event may be the closest you can get.

Comment: I was not optimistic it would. The only progress bars I've ever seen involved some looping code structure. Access is not multi-thread capable. I don't see how a form load process can pass status info to a progress bar process. What exactly do you mean by 'unbound object controls' - OLEObject? - and what exactly are these charts loaded from?

Comment: Although, Access does have a progress bar that displays when a long query is running. Haven't really noticed it for other activities. Maybe I don't have any others that are slow enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Form_Open`, in conjunction with some `DoEvents` to actually make stuff show up when executing.

`Form_Open` is the very first event that should trigger when opening a form, before any data is loaded.

If you don't do a `DoEvents` after setting a progress bar, the UI might not refresh.
In my experience it doesn't matter for progress bars, but a liberal use of `DoEvents` in long running code never hurts (allows for Ctrl + Break to work to terminate the code, among other things).

You can unset the progress bar in `Form_Current` which should fire when a record has loaded, and use a property (that is set to `True` in `Form_Open` and `False` in `Form_Current`) to check if there's a progress bar to remove.